# Can't figure out how to allow user to set install path

Tags: vb.net, installation, windows-installer

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in VB.NET.
I have gone through the publish section in the program properties. 
There is a Publish Location section and I have that set where I want, 
but when you install the program, it never asks where you want to install it
and it installs in the the User AppData folder.

In the publish properties there is a section for Installation Folder URL. 
But it only will allow a web url and not a file path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing ClickOnce setups (that's the Publish) and MSI setups (which require you to create a setup project to buold an MSI file). ClickOnce doesn't sound like what you need if you want files in the UserAppDataFolder location.

Comment: I have gone through and created an installer, but I keep getting an error saying my application identity is not set.  It happens at this line ----------  System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed

Comment: If you're still using Publish then stop. That is not an MSI-based setup project.

Comment: I know it is not.  I created an installer and i copied the application files direction from my projects folder and I am getting the error that I just stated above.

Comment: You need to look at your code again and start from scratch with your app and the install. MSI setups don't require .NET at all. If your app is failing with that error then you've still got a ClickOnce deployment class in your code!!!